# Storing fetched json dictionaries in array resulting in nil

Tags: ios, json

I have a database of files with attributes such as url, title, and timestamp.  When I load a certain view controller, I'm fetching the file data and loading it into a tableview.  Because there are multiple files each with their 3 attributes, I'm trying to save the data in an array, then go through each object in the array and extract the JSON data.  As of now, the GET request and response are successful, but the array remains nil.  Is my approach wrong?

```
 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        guard let data = data, response = response else
        {
            print("No data or response!")
            return
        }

        let strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Body: \(strData)", terminator: "")

        do {
            self.fetchedArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSArray


            print("fetched array count is %i \(self.fetchedArray!.count)")


            if let jsonArray: NSArray = self.fetchedArray{


                for var i = 0; i<jsonArray.count; ++i {


                    let dictResult = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary

                    let recording = Recordings()
                    recording.trackURL = dictResult["url"] as? String
                    recording.trackTimestamp = dictResult["timestamp"] as? String
                    recording.trackAuthor = dictResult["author"] as? String
                    recording.trackTitle = dictResult["title"] as? String
                    self.recordings?.addObject(recording)

                    }
            }
            else
            {
                // No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("No error thrown but could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }
        }
        catch let parseError {
            // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
            print(parseError)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error thrown. could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
```

As now its executing the second to last else statement `print("No error thrown but could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")` and printing out all the data.

Log of data before serialization:

```
Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7c349990> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/serve_current_user_files } { status code: 200, headers {
"Content-Length" = 239;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Sat, 03 Oct 2015 02:53:00 GMT";
Server = "Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.10";
"Set-Cookie" = "session=eyJfZnJlc2giOnRydWUsIl9pZCI6eyIgYiI6Ik16RXhaRGs0TldVM1lUQmxNREJrWlRNeFpqZ3pZMkl3T1dRNE5EZzVPREk9In0sInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxIn0.CPDUjA.Mm56VPuZPIokCZVoRw7X2ySz960; HttpOnly; Path=/";
} }Body: Optional({
  "recordings": [
  {
  "author": 1, 
  "timestamp": "Sun, 27 Sep 2015 17:44:54 GMT", 
  "title": "Test1.m4a", 
  "url": "/Users/allahesharghi/Desktop/Omid/pythonprojects/sound/sound/uploads/omid1/Test1.m4a"
}
]
```

Comment: Make sure the data is valid.<br/> In    print("Body: \(strData)", terminator: "") Does it print the result that what you want?

Comment: The only print statement that gets executed is the print within the second to last else statement since the array is coming out nil.  The data is looking correct.

Comment: I meant before serialise json objects, make sure the data is correct.  or post your logs here, that would be easier to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is:

```
{
    "recordings": [
        {
            "author": 1,
            "timestamp": "Sun, 27 Sep 2015 17:44:54 GMT",
            "title": "Test1.m4a",
            "url": "/Users/allahesharghi/Desktop/Omid/pythonprojects/sound/sound/uploads/omid1/Test1.m4a"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, the root object isn't an array, it is a dictionary with an array of dictionaries for  the key `recordings`.  This means that when you say

```
self.fetchedArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSArray
```

self.fetchedArray will be nil because the downcast to `NSArray` will fail, because an NSDictionary can't be downcast to an NSArray.

You need to access the root dictionary and then access the array from the recordings key -

```
do {
       someDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
       self.fetchedArray = someDictionary!["results"] as? NSArray
            print("fetched array count is %i \(self.fetchedArray!.count)")
...
```

Comment: You're right.  However, I tried implementing this and I get an error saying "cannot subscript a value of type NSDictionary?" when I set `self.fetchedArray = someDictionary`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't unwrapping the optional dictionary